# Access Home Menu Buttons Grayed out

Tags: ms-access

I have had a new issue pop up.  I am in an Access 2013 database I have been working in for some time and all of a sudden several of the buttons on the Home menu are grayed out as soon as I open the database.  The one I am most concerned about is the "View" button.  I have a query experiencing issues opening because of another query's name change.  First off, I am confused as to why it didn't just automatically update in the query like it usually does, but aside from that, I want to open the query in SQL view to fix it, but since the "View" button is grayed out, I can't.  Anyone know how I can get this fixed?

I have tried opening it exclusive, compact/repair, make a copy of the database and open that one, and glanced through the Options to see if anything looks awry, although I may have missed something here.  I am the only one accessing this database - no one else on the team has Access to even open the file.

[image]

Comment: If you don't have a form open there is nothing to change the view on so it will be greyed out.Open a form.

Comment: Indeed. Right-click the object or use Ctrl+Enter to open it in Design view.

Comment: If you're wondering "what changed?" it is possible that the default form to display got unset. I've seen this happen sometimes. If you are used to there being a form open right away and no form opens immediately maybe that is throwing you for a loop. Reset this via `File > Access Options > Current Database > Display Form` (or check your AutoExec macro if you are using that)

Comment: So it isn't a form I am trying to open, it's a query.  But either way, when I have a table or query selected, the button is still grayed out.  I just realized it seems to be across all my Access databases, so that is equally weird.  I can right click and choose "Design" mode - that isn't an issue.  And once in Design mode, I can switch to SQL mode.  But I know in the past I have been able to select a query and choose SQL right off the bat, which would allow me to change the query without going in Design mode.  But that option no longer seems to be available with the button being grayed out.

Comment: @DBerg75 I don't know if I've seen the behavior you're describing. That `View` button on the home ribbon tab operates on the currently opened object (form, query, report, whatever). Right clicking on the object in the navigation pane, for me, has only ever brought up Open and Design. I'd like it to bring up SQL but I have not seem that on queries.